# Angular 7: How to properly this.http.get from a nested response?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm doing the **Angular 7** tutorial wonder how to **properly request a list of items** if they are not on the top level, but **nested**:

**Top-Level (works)**

```
[
  { id: 123, name: 'Name 123'},
  { id: 124, name: 'Name 124'},
  // ...
]
```

**Nested (doesn't work)**

```
{
  message: 'x items found.',
  data: [
    { id: 123, name: 'Name 123'},
    { id: 124, name: 'Name 124'},
    // ...
  ]
}
```

**Service**

```
// ...
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ItemService {
  private apiUrl = 'api/items'; // items are in .data

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getItems (): Observable<Item[]> {      
    // Here is the problem:
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(this.apiUrl, {
      pathToItems: 'data' // <- Pseudocode
    });
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
// ...
this.itemService.getItems()
  .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
```

I could use `subscribe()` in the service and return the content of `.data`, but I think there should be a more simple solution. I need to keep the return type (array of `Item`).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what the structure of `Item` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RxJs filters like [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) or [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html). That's one of the advantages when using RxJs (Observables). You can filter your data before you pass it to your component.

An example:

```js
return this.http.get(ITEMS_URL).pipe(
  filter(response => response.filter(data => data.message === "SUCCEEDED")),
  map(response => response.map(data => data.items))
);
```

Comment: I think giving a short example (maybe even use the nested data from the question) would make your answer even better. I think especially map is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @KimKern Added example.